# Porque a transparência da imagem no Botão não funciona do Firefox?

Tags: html, css, navegador-de-internet, css-hover

Eu tenho esse código que nada mais é que uma imagem com opacidade dentro de um `button`. No Chrome funciona normalmente, mas no Firefox fica bugado, como podem ver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código referente à imagem acima:

```css
button {
    padding: 10px;
}

.images {
    opacity: 0.25;
}

.images:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
    <img class="images" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
</button>
<button type="button">
    <img class="images" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Além do Firefox, também acontece no IE11. Por ser um botão, os eventos do mouse (mouseover, mouseleave, etc.) ficam todos vinculados ao próprio botão, e não aos seus elementos-filhos. Com isso, um `:hover` aplicado diretamente a um elemento-filho do `button` não irá responder. Se é um bug ou não (há sinalizações para isso como citou a resposta do Netinho) eu não posso afirmar, mas é a forma que esses navegadores tratam esse caso.

Mas acho difícil ser um bug. Veja que o [link no Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843003) apontado na resposta do Netinho é de 6 anos atrás. De lá pra cá o Firefox sofreu muitas atualizações (assim como o IE). Se fosse realmente um bug, creio que já teria sido corrigido.

Mas uma forma de contornar isso é colocando o `:hover` no botão apontando para o elemento-filho:

```css
button {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.images {
    opacity: 0.25;
}

button:hover .images{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
    <img class="images" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
</button>
```

> Note que até a propriedade `cursor: pointer;` teve que ser aplicada ao
>   `button` e não à imagem. Caso contrário, também não responderia.

Comment: Legal tio, parece que é isso mesmo, e eu ainda preservo a opacidade do botão intacta, só a imagem que muda a opacidade. Vlw

Answer (score 1):

Recentemente tive um problema parecido e consegui resolver aplicando o evento `hover` no elemento pai, ou seja, no `button`. Aparentemente no Firefox, os elementos filhos da tag `button` não são candidatos válidos ao `hover`. Há um relatório no [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) referente a a esse problema: [Children of button does not respond to :hover](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=843003)

**Exemplo**
:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
}

button {
  opacity: 0.25;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
    <img class="images" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
</button>
<button type="button">
    <img class="images" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
</button>
```